# What is the .screenrc file for?

Tags: shell, terminal

What is the `.screenrc` file for? I have seen it in some dotfiles repos and such but I don't quite understand what it's for.

Judging from the name it sets settings for the Terminal itself, not the shell, am I correct on this? I suppose not, in that case, what is it actually for? And does it change from shell to shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/.screenrc` is the user-specific configuration file for [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). You can find more information in the [user manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Startup-Files).

Comment: Ah I see, OK, don't know how I didn't think of that. Basically the equivalent of `.tmux.conf` but for Screen. Thanks!